# Transforming into Map using Java 8 and lambdas

Tags: java, lambda

I have

```
List<Gift> gifts = new ArrayList<>();
gifts .add(new Gift().withType(INF, CHD));
gifts .add(new Gift().withType(ADT, CHD));
gifts .add(new Gift().withType(INF, ADT));
```

Gift has a method `List<Type> getTypes()`;

and now I'd like to transform gifts list into something like
`Map<Type,List<Gift>>`.
I'd like to do it with Java 8 and lambdas in one line. Is it possible?

```
public class Gift {

    public List<Type> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public Gift withType(Type... types) {
        this.types = Arrays.asList(types);
        return this;
    }

    List<Type> types = new ArrayList<>();
}

public enum Type {
    ADT,
    CHD,
    INF;
}
```

Previous old code (it looks awfully). That's all what I have.

```
Map<Type, List<Gift>> byTypes = new HashMap<>();

for (Gift gift : gifts) {
    for (Type type : gift.getTypes()) {
        List<Gift> giftList = byTypes.get(type);
        if (giftList == null) {
            giftList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        giftList.add(gift);
        byTypes.put(type,giftList);
    }
}
```

Comment: So each `Gift` has two `Type` associated with it? Can you please show your `Gift` class? Also, how do identify a `Gift` as a unique `Gift`. That's important because you need to know what is the `key` for the `Map`

Comment: What about my second question? *Also, how do identify a Gift as a unique Gift*.

Comment: There is no speciall method for indentify  Gift

Answer (score 3):

Using Guava's [Multimap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html):

```
ListMultimap<Type, Gift> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();

gifts.forEach(g -> g.getTypes().forEach(t -> multimap.put(t, g)));

Map<Type, Collection<Gift>> map = multimap.asMap();
```

Comment: Don't you mean `forEach(t -> multimap.put(t, g))`?

Comment: OK, but here still is "intermediate" element (multimap). I am wondering of it is possible to ommit it. Using only streams and lambdas.

Comment: @LostIntime Even if that was remotely possible, that would be a highly unreadable solution. That being said, there is still a way to use an intermediate value and achieve the same result using Java-8 if you don't want to use Guava.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found solution which satify me :-) I wrote my collector :-D

```
Map<Type, List<Gift>> collect1 = gifts.stream().collect(new TypeToManyGiftCollector());

public class TypeToManyGiftCollector
        implements Collector<Gift, Map<Type, List<Gift>>, Map<Type, List<Gift>>> {

    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<Type, List<Gift>>> supplier() {
        return () -> new HashMap<Type, List<Gift>>() {{
            for (Type type : Type.values()) {
                put(type, new ArrayList<Gift>());
            }
        }};
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<Type, List<Gift>>, Gift> accumulator() {
        return (Map<Type, List<Gift>> map, Gift gift) -> {
            gift.getTypes().stream().forEach(type -> map.get(type).add(gift));
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<Type, List<Gift>>> combiner() {
        return (Map<Type, List<Gift>> map1, Map<Type, List<Gift>> map2) ->
        {
            for (Type type : Type.values()) {
                map1.get(type).addAll(map2.get(type));
            }
            return map1;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<Type, List<Gift>>, Map<Type, List<Gift>>> finisher() {
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(IDENTITY_FINISH));
    }
}
```

Comment: I just love the way how you put the initialization of the `HashMap` in the `supplier()` method into something of syntactical beauty and elegance. I think I can read your code like a novel.

Answer (score 0):

Reintroducing your intermediate Pair class `P`, but in a slightly different way. I think we might expect that in later iterations of Java, this is going to become much more common place and easier to do with the introduction of a built-in Pair type, and the implementation of [Value Objects](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/169).

```
package play;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import static play.Type.*;

public class Play {
  static class P<K,V> { K k; V v; P(K kk,V vv) {k=kk;v=vv;}}
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Gift> gifts = new ArrayList<>();
    gifts .add(new Gift().withType(INF, CHD));
    gifts .add(new Gift().withType(ADT, CHD));
    gifts .add(new Gift().withType(INF, ADT));
    Map<Type,List<Gift>> m = gifts.stream()
      .flatMap((g)->g.getTypes().stream().map((t)->new P<>(t,g)))
      .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
          (p)->p.k,
          // Does not work with <code>new EnumMap<>(Type.class)</code>
          // I dont know why, ...
          ()->new EnumMap(Type.class),
          Collectors.mapping(
            (p)->p.v, 
            Collectors.toList() 
          )
        )
      );
    System.out.println("Map: "+m.toString());
  }
}
```

My only problem in this code is that I cannot explain the need for a 'Untyped' Map as the Map factory. Feel free to explain if you know why ...

Answer (score 0):

I found other solution with a reduce method. In my opinion smaller one and easier to understand.

```
      HashMap<Type, List<Gift>> result = gifts.stream().reduce(
            new HashMap<Type, List<Gift>>() {{
                asList(Type.values()).stream().forEach(type -> put(type, new ArrayList<>()));
            }}
            ,
            (map, gift) -> {
                gift.getTypes().stream().forEach(type -> map.get(type).add(gift));
                return map;
            }
            ,
            (map1, map2) -> {
                asList(Type.values()).stream().forEach(type -> map1.get(type).addAll(map2.get(type)));
                return map1;
            }
    );
```